# How to set the colsize of highchart heatmap with irregular data

Tags: highcharts

I am facing issue while setting colsize dynamically for heatmap cell which plots irregular sensor data, pls help to solve the issue.

I have attached link to jsfiddle for sample data and how it is configured in my code.
Jsfiddle link = "https://jsfiddle.net/kalavathi/f3toq7s6/32/"

for this kind of data how to caculate the colsize of the heatmap dynamically so that all the data is clearly visible to the user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62392940/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @Kalavathi B, How would you like to arrange your data? If you set `colsize` property to a smaller value, the data is clearly visible, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/94q0cn2k/

Comment: @ppotaczek,Thanks for your time and reply. If we set the colsize to some fixed value it only works for less data  Ex:jsfiddle.net/kalavathi/fqhm9sep/4 . But if we use the same fixed colsize for more data then all the data points will not be visible in the chart ,Ex: jsfiddle.net/kalavathi/yLvqxuga/24 .So I need some way to calculate the colsize dynamically based on the data size to show all the data values clearly to the end user.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. You can dynamically calculate the `colsize` property, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3jfs8ruw/ but this won't help if your data has big differences in x values, like in the second example. You would have to divide your data into several series with different `colsize`, but this will cause the columns to have different widths.

Comment: @ ppotaczek,Thanks for the solution.I have tried your calculation but we are facing columns to have different widths issue and sometimes cells are overalapping with large colsize.

Comment: @Kalavathi B, Could you provide me with some visualization that shows how you would like your chart to look like?